# Classic ASP Type Mismatch using .NET DLL

Tags: vb.net, asp-classic, com-interop

I have a problem trying to access data pulled as an array from a VB.NET DLL.

The DLL is registered correctly and working on the web server which is serving the asp classic pages.

I have tested the dll using a vb6 program and it retrieved the data that I expect.
Here is the code that I used for that.

```
Dim commItems
commItems = c.GetCommTypes

For i = LBound(commItems) To UBound(commItems)
    Me.Label2.Caption = "Item: " & commItems(i).CommTypeID & " - " & commItems(i).CommTypeName
    DoEvents
    Sleep (1000)
Next
```

The error message I get is as follows, when trying to do the same thing is asp clasic

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'

Type mismatch

/commtype.asp, line 13
```

Here is my asp code

```
Dim Core    
Set Core = Server.Createobject("Advantage.Dealer.Email.CoreClassLibrary.CoreClass") 

dim commItems
commItems = Core.GetCommTypes

For i = LBound(commItems) to UBound(commItems)
    Response.Write commItems(i).CommTypeID

Next
```

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong but if i run this code

```
Dim Core    
Set Core = Server.Createobject("Advantage.Dealer.Email.CoreClassLibrary.CoreClass") 

dim commItems
commItems = Core.GetCommTypes

For i = LBound(commItems) to UBound(commItems)
    Response.Write  i
Next
```

I get

```
0123
```

So something is working, but not how I want it to.

Please be aware that it should return 4 rows of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after a few more hours searching I found the solution I was looking for.

I found the answer here
http://bytes.com/topic/asp-classic/answers/167046-type-mismatch-error-when-accessing-array

Right at the bottom of the post.

Basically I was passing an array of my class type, and what I should have been doing is returning an array of System.Object type.  I made some changes to my .net DLL so that rather than returning an array of the CommType Class it was returning an Array of System.Object

Answer (score 0):

I would review the COM interface for the type returned in the array by the Core.GetCommTypes() method.

<InsiderKnowledge>

The Advantage.Dealer.Email.ModelClassLibrary.CommType class does not appear to have a COM interface declared.

This does not tally with your VB6 client successfully being able to consume its properties. Have you modified your assembly/assemblies between executing your VB6 and VB Script tests against them?

</InsiderKnowledge>